# On what basics we give url and name in laravel route file

Tags: php, laravel

You may find me stupid but i am unable to understand on what basics we give url and name in our route file

Example:

```
 Route::get('/order/getOrders', 'OrderController@getOrders')- 
 >name('order.getOrders')->middleware('auth');
```

can anyone please tell me.
and if we take url on the basics of where our file in view folder like( order->getorder blade file)

Then what if my path is layouts.site.topbar

In view instead of pages, my file is in layouts.

***EDIT:***

blade file

```
          <a  href="{{ route('sync.index') }}">

                    @if(isset($syncs))
                      @foreach ($syncs as $sync)
                      @endforeach
                      {{ $sync->session_date }}

                    @endif
            </a>
```

controller file

class TopbarController extends Controller
{

```
      public function index()
{ die('o');
   $syncNames = Sync::select('session_date','session_time')->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();

    return view('layouts.site.topbar', array(
            'syncs' =>$syncNames
        ));

}

public function sync_finish_session() {
    die('s');
    $user_id = Auth::id();
   $sync_date = date('M d ',strtotime("now"));
   $sync_time = date('M d, Y H:i:s',strtotime("now"));

     $sync = Sync::where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
         if(count( $sync) > 0) {
                    Sync::where('user_id',$user_id)->update(['session_date'=>$sync_date,'session_time'=>$sync_time,'user_id'=>$user_id]);

                }
                else {

       $dates = new Sync();
       $dates->session_date = $sync_date;
       $dates->session_time = $sync_time;
       $dates->user_id = $user_id;
        $dates->save();
        }

        return $sync;

}
```

}

web file

```
Route::post('/sync_finish_session', 'TopbarController@sync_finish_session')->name('sync_finish_session')->middleware('auth');
```

Route::get('/sync/index', 'TopbarController@index')->name('sync.index')->middleware('auth');

Now whats the problem its giving nothing even i put die but its not going in controller file.

Comment: Actually `name('order.getOrders')` is not where you can put the path of view. It is kind of route variable which you can use inside view, js, html form etc

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but you can name your route anything you want. If you want, you can call your above route `kerbholz` (`->name('kerbholz')`) and later in a view file you can use this name as a "shorthand": `{{ route('kerbholz') }}` will print `/order/getOrders`.

Comment: ok i understand, now my problem is let me show you my code what i have made so far with the help of you comment.

Comment: i will be editing my code.

Comment: @kerbholz please answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more a personal preference thing than that there are rules.

The convention I use is `name(<model>.<action>)`

This way i can create routes like

```
Route::get('/users/{id}/view', 'UserController@view')->name('users.specific.view')->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just name route as you do want. There is no strict rules how to name route.  You can change name('order.getOrders') to name("anyName") and use new name in templates.

Answer (score 0):

As the [Laravel documentaton](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes) about rounting says:

> Named routes allow the convenient generation of URLs or redirects for specific routes.

So, you can use this `name` to generate URLs or redirects. For example:

You could put this in your `web.php` file:

`Route::get('/image/index', 'API\SettingsController@index')->name('image.index');`

And call that route like this in your view:

`<a href="{{ route('image.index') }}">Le met see that index!</a>`

Where the `{{ route('image.index') }}` references the name you gave to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can name your route(s) anything you want. If you wanted, you could call your above route "mySuperCoolRouteName":

```
Route::get('/order/getOrders', 'OrderController@getOrders')- 
 >name('mySuperCoolRouteName')->middleware('auth');
```

and later in a view file you can use this name as a "shorthand" to get/print the URL of that route:

`<a href="{{ route('mySuperCoolRouteName') }}">To My Cool Route</a>`

will be rendered to

`<a href="/order/getOrders">To My Cool Route</a>`

Comment: ok @kerbholz, I did as you said but the problem is my view file is not going in controller file. I tried everything which is to my knowledge. You can see the code above as I edit my question.

Comment: See if running `php artisan route:cache` to clear and cache your routes file helps. You can also use `php artisan route:list` to list all of your routes to make sure your routes are there.

Comment: Also ... your `@foreach` won't show anything, move `{{ $sync->session_date }}` inside your `@foreach`

Comment: Yes @kerbholz its there both index and second one both in the list and I also cleared the cache but same result

Comment: And that `index()` function is inside your `TopbarController`? (Just making sure, you used a different controller in your original question). And you're on `/sync/index` on your server? Take a look at your Laravel log `/storage/logs/laravel.log` and see if there are any errors/warnings

Comment: This is the error "Undefined variable: syncs (View: D:\xamp\htdocs\stocky3\resources\views\layouts\site\topbar.blade.php) (View: D:\xamp\htdocs\stocky3\resources\views\layouts\site\topbar.blade.php) (View: D:\xamp\htdocs\stocky3\resources\views\layouts\site\topbar.blade.php and     
                                                                                                                          
         i put {{ $sync->session_date }} inside foreach

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but this sounds like a complete new question now, different Controllers, nothing about naming routes anymore. Please open another question here on SO and describe your problem in detail, show controller names, explain what you are trying to do, error messages etc. If you want you can mention me or just let me know of your newly asked question

Comment: I have to wait for 4 days for opening a new question. I am totally new in laravel. so I asked two more questions before so they said to wait for 4 days that is why I am asking here. I already gave my two days to this problem. so I am here